# class в PYTHONe

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

```
class Field:
def __init__(self, ships=[]):
    self._ships = ships

def shoot_at(self, tuple):
    pass

def field_without_ships(self):
    pass

def field_with_ships(self):
    lst = [[' ' for b in range(10)] for i in range(10)]
    print(lst)
print(Field.field_with_ships())
```

С табуляцией все в порядке просто скопировал криво.
Вот такая ошибка

```
TypeError: field_with_ships() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

В чем проблема и будет ли она появляться с другими методами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 варианта:

```
field = Field()
field.field_with_ships()
```

или

```
@staticmethod
def field_with_ships():
   ...
```

или

```
@classmethod
def field_with_ships(cls):
   ...
```

Дело в том, что Вы объявили метод `field_with_ship` как обычный метод класса, и его нужно вызывать от имени экземпляра этого класса (тем самым передавая экземпляр, как первый аргумент)

Если Ваш метод класса не подразумевает ни наличия объекта ни атрибутов самого класса, то его лучше объявить как `@staticmethod`. Это нужно будет написать перед каждым таким методом. Если используются атрибуты класса (общие для всех объектов), то `@classmethod`, например

```
class A:
   x = 1
   @classmethod
   def clsmethod(cls):
      print(cls.x)
   def __init__(self, y)
      self.y = y
   def objmetod(self):
      print(self.y)
   @staticmethod
   def statmethod():
      print('Hello, world')


A.clsmethod()  # --> 1
A.statmethod()  # --> Hello, world
a = A(42)
a.objmethod()  # --> 42
```

Comment: тоесть нужно ко всем подписать staticmethod? а @staticmethod работает ко всем функция что написание под ним или только к одной?

Comment: @lalalala дописал в ответе